# Image not getting displayed in react project

Tags: reactjs

This is my App.js. Here, I call the "Profile" Component.

```
import './App.css';
import Profile from "./Profile"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Profile />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then, inside Profile.js, I call Card component and inside the Card component, I've enclosed an image.

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from './Card'
import styles from "./Profile.module.css"
import image1 from "./assets/profile1.png"
const Profile = () => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <div>
        <img src={image1} alt="" />
      </div>

    </Card>
  )
}

export default Profile
```

Inside of Card component, I've just applied some CSS to make it look like a Card.

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from "./Card.module.css"

const Card = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.card}>

    </div>
  )
}export default Card
```

This is my folder structure.

[image]

I'm really confused why the image isn't getting showed up. Currently this is the output I'm getting.

[image]

I've restarted the server as well. But it's not getting fixed.

Comment: In your browser, open the devtools and check the network panel to see the request that's going out.  Seems like you might have an incorrect path structure; you'll be able to see it easily from the devtools where it is trying to load the image from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your card doesn't have a child component return maybe that could be the problem

```
    import React from 'react'
    import styles from "./Card.module.css"
    
    const Card = ({children}) => {
      return (
        <div className={styles.card}>
    {children}
        </div>
      )
    }
export default Card
```

try this

Comment: Why does it fix the issue(It did indeed)?

Comment: when you pass something wrapping your custom component it will take that tag as a children's tag.. you have to specify that.